# How to initialize a char array without the null terminator?

Tags: c, arrays, string, c11, null-terminated

The char array is a part of network message, which has well defined length, so the null terminator is not needed.

```
struct Cmd {
    char cmd[4];
    int arg;
}

struct Cmd cmd { "ABCD" , 0 }; // this would be buffer overflow
```

How can I initialize this cmd member char array? without using functions like `strncpy`?

Comment: You need to initialize the structure variable like this:- struct Cmd cmd{ {'A','B','C','D'}, 0}; . If you give "ABCD",  it is considered as string literal and will be stored in const char pointer and string literal ends with '\0' .

Comment: @sonulohani no, this is not "needed". Besides the missing `=` the given initialization is fine.

Comment: @JensGustedt The trick with C silently skipping the null terminator is dangerous - a language flaw in my opinion. Providing a `{'A','B','C','D'}` initializer is therefore good practice: it is self-documenting code showing that the programmer is aware of the lack of null termination, but it also allows compilers/static analysers to give a warning elsewhere in the code, when a string literal initializer results in a string that is not null terminated.

Comment: @Lundin "needed" and "good practice" is not the same thing.

Comment: @JensGustedt You wrote that the initialization is fine. But it is not, since it contains a potential subtle bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terminating null character is ignored if the size of the `char` array is the same as the number of characters in the initializer. So `cmd` will not have the null terminator.

The relevant section in the C11 standard (n1570) is [6.7.9/14](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character *if there is room*** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

And the statement:

```
struct Cmd cmd { "ABCD" , 0 };
```

should be:

```
struct Cmd cmd  = { "ABCD" , 0 };
```

Comment: Note that this is yet another area where C and C++ have different views on how things should work.  C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2012) §8.5 Initializers, §8.5.2 Character arrays, ¶2: There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [ Example:
`char cv[4] = "asdf"; // error`
is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing ’\0’. —end example ]

Comment: does that means C++ is different than C on this issue?

Comment: @fluter:Yes. In C++, it is ill-formed. Meaning, it is not a valid program.(program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition Rule)