# Assign part of a string to a char array

Tags: c++

Edit: After asking this question I was informed about the question [How to initialize a char array without the null terminator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105682/how-to-initialize-a-char-array-without-the-null-terminator) which is almost identical. (I'm building a network packet as well.)

I'll keep this question open anyway, because I'm just assigning and not initializing.

---

I have a fixed size array that I would like to assign a fixed text to:

```c
char text[16];
text = "0123456789abcdef";
```

Of course this doesn't work because the right hand side contains the null terminator.

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [17]' to 'char [16]'
```

The text is human-readable, so I would prefer to keep it in one piece, i.e. not write `{'0', '1', ...}`.

Can I make the assignment work somehow?

By the way, I only have a few hundred bytes of RAM, so preferably (but second to the human-readability requirement) the solution shouldn't use twice the RAM for a temporary copy or something like that.

Comment: In C, `strcpy(text, "0123456789abcde"); /* text has space for 15 "real" characters and the zero terminator */` Note that ``strcpy(text, "0123456789abcdef");`` is an error!

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? There is a difference.

Comment: `char text[] = "0123456789abcdef";`

Comment: C use null terminated string, which mean storing string with 16 character require 17 byte.

Comment: @AndrewHenle's suggestion has my vote ... however it creates an array of 17 bytes, not 16 as in the original OP's question :)

Comment: So the question is about how to store 17 bytes in 16 byte array?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan The question is about storing 16 bytes and discarding the null terminator.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen C++

Comment: @AndreKR Then see [**How to initialize a char array without the null terminator?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105682/how-to-initialize-a-char-array-without-the-null-terminator)  TLDR: `char text[16] = "0123456789abcdef";` (note that won't work in C++)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed my question is almost a duplicate of that one, only that it's not during initialization (but it could be actually if I refactor a bit).

Answer (score 2):

If you write in C:

```
char text[16];
strncpy(text, "0123456789abcdef", sizeof(text));
```

Note that `text` will not have the null-terminator and won't be compatible with the standard C functions like `strlen`. If the text if human-readable, I recommend to include the terminator. It is only one character but it will make your life much easier.

Example:

```
char text[17];
strncpy(text, "0123456789abcdef", sizeof(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in case you have any misunderstanding -- `"0123456789abcdef"` is a string literal. Its type is `const char [17]`, not `const char [16]`, because this string literal has a null terminator `\0` in the end.

Then I assume you do mean **assignment** not initialization. They are different.

I can think of multiple ways to do the assignment. You may choose based on your needs.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using std::size_t;

template<size_t N>
void print(const char (&a)[N])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
        putchar(a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

void foo1()
{
    char text[16];
    std::memcpy(text, "0123456789abcdef", sizeof text);
    print(text);
}

void foo2()
{
    char text[16];
    std::string("0123456789abcdef").copy(text, sizeof text);
    print(text);
}

void foo3()
{
    char text[16];
    std::string_view("0123456789abcdef").copy(text, sizeof text);
    print(text);
}

// programmer needs to make sure access with src is valid
template<size_t N>
void assign(char (& dest)[N], const char * src)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
        dest[i] = *src++;
}

void foo4()
{
    char text[16];
    assign(text, "0123456789abcdef");
    print(text);
}

int main()
{
    foo1();    // 0123456789abcdef
    foo2();    // 0123456789abcdef
    foo3();    // 0123456789abcdef
    foo4();    // 0123456789abcdef
    return 0;
}
```

Some remarks:

- `std::memcpy` is the traditional memory copy way from C
- `std::string_view` is a light-weight view on a string, introduced in C++17
- Or you may write your own function like `assign()` -- with a template you can tell the size of an array at compile time. Depending on your needs, you may decide whether or not to implement bounds checking.